# uninstall eslint using yarn

Tags: node.js, typescript, eslint

i was trying to use eslint in nodejs TS project

using this rules

```
rules: {
    '@typescript-eslint/interface-name-prefix': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars': 'off',
    'no-console': 'warn',
    // "max-len": ["error", { "code": 80 }],
    'object-curly-spacing': ['error', 'always'],
    'arrow-parens': ['error', 'as-needed'],
},
```

then i wanted to write a function for authenticate

```
import fastifyJWT from 'fastify-jwt'
```

i am getting this error

**implicitly has an 'any' type**

tried to stop eslint many ways using line skip - file skip

and now i want to remove it completely

i installed it using yarn

then uninstall it with all eslint related packages from package.json

i am still getting errors

tried  `npm eslin -v` 
getting this 9.5.1

checked
`npm list -g` and `yarn list -g` and did not find the package

Comment: `fastify-jwt` is `This package has TypeScript declarations provided by @types/fastify-jwt`, you have to `yarn add --dev @types/fastify-jwt` or use https://yarnpkg.com/api/modules/plugin_typescript.html

Comment: Just edit `package.json` manually and then `yarn install`